# How to colorize custom C++ types in Sublimetext?

Tags: c++, sublimetext3

I have a C++ file with a header defining custom types.
Sublime text properly recognizes autocomplete on those types.

I would like those custom types to have a specific text color.

Is it possible? How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is called semantic highlighting. Sublime doesn't have support for it out of the box, but there is a plugin called [`Colorcoder`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Colorcoder) that says it can do it. However, the plugin was last updated 8 years ago, and *a lot* has changed in Sublime since then, not the least of which is the [language definitions used for syntax highlighting](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages) have been dramatically expanded and improved. The way these definitions are written has also changed, from XML-based to YAML. Sublime still supports the old XML version, though, so there's no reason this plugin wouldn't work in that regard. However, because most/all of the syntax definitions have been revamped, the highlighting that you see in C++ files (for example) before you install the plugin and after you install it may be different. YMMV.

Looking at the download stats on the Package Control page I linked above, this still seems to be a fairly popular plugin, so one would assume it still works, at least to some extent. I'd recommend trying it out (unfortunately, I'm not set up to test it where I'm working today), because it is currently the only package in Package Control that advertises this feature.